# Check for same index in two arrays: IN (1,2,3) AND IN (A, B, C)

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to pair two arrays in MySQL. They should match only by its index.  Meaning that if a = 1, b = 2, and c = 3, the array(1,2,3) would match against array(a,b,c) and return 1,2,3, while (b,a,c) won't. Which should only return '3'.

**My code**

I have two `arrays` which I am sending to the SQL server. The first is the `ids` of the questions I am answering. The second is the answers.

I have done this:

```
SELECT
  id, title
FROM
  `questions` q
WHERE
  q.id IN (2, 4) AND q.answer IN ('Christoffer Columbus', 'Arnold Schwarzenegger')
;
```

... This checks if `id` 2 equals 'Christoffer Columbus' **AND** 'Arnold Schwarzenegger'. So if you answer 'Christoffer Columbus' on both question 1 and 2, it will be correct. That's not so good... :-)

Can you help me with this one? How do I solve this?

Comment: Well I am new to this :-) ... Can you point me in the right direction to how to solve this?

Comment: It'd be better **NOT** to use MySQL, and use some other form of database system(like NoSQL).

Comment: I don't like the whole design, in general. A better option would be to pull the correct answer from the database (eg: `SELECT id, answer FROM questions WHERE id IN (2,4)`), and then check for correctness on the application side. A disadvantage in doing it the way you want is that it will never return any rows which have an incorrect answer, and I reckon you'd want to provide some feedback to the user as to what the correct answer actually was.

Comment: @BackinaFlash And what's wrong with MySQL? I'm all for alternative solutions, but this is *perfect* for SQL databases.

Comment: @NullUserException NoSQL was designed to work for key->value storage specifically.

Comment: @BackinaFlash I don't see a problem with SQL, ie: there's no *disadvantage* in using SQL here.

Comment: I didn't say that it's disadvantageous; I just referred better to use something made for this than to waste time figuring stuff out in SQL.

Comment: If the document is tabular in nature, then a RDBMS is going to be a better fit.

Comment: @BackinaFlash you _really_ don't know SQL do you? It's much more powerful than you might realize, it being a 4GL with lots of ninja skills built into most engines to make getting back data far faster than a naive map-reduce.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you're looking for this:

```
Select
  id, title
From
  `questions` q
Where
  (q.id = 2 And q.answer = 'Christoffer Columbus') Or
  (q.id = 4 And q.answer = 'Arnold Schwarzenegger')
;
```

You need to add a similar criteria for each pair from the arrays.

Answer (score 4):

+1 to @Laurence's answer, but FWIW you can also use tuple-comparisons to express the same condition, like this:

```
Where
  (q.id, q.answer) IN ((2, 'Christoffer Columbus'), (4, 'Arnold Schwarzenegger'))
```

Comment: Thank you too Bill. Laurence's answer makes more sense in my context, but thank you anyway... :-)